# is it possible to use Auto-Event Variable as Event Tracking Parameters

Tags: google-tag-manager

I would like to use an Auto-Event Variable like **{{element id}}** as a Event Tracking Parameters.

For example:

```
Tag type = Universal Analytics
Track Type = Event
Category = some text
Action = some text
Label = some text
Value = {{element id}}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to add a macro as {{element id}}, but if you want to have something like "ID: {{element id}}" it requires empty space between macro and string, otherwise it won't work.